# Does .write(string) replace all file with the new string or just append it?

Tags: python, html, file, python-requests

The coding that I am using to learn:

```
import requests


r = requests.get("http://google.com")

f = open("./page.html", "w+")
f.write(r.text)
```

So if i understand all right this will create a .html file and write the google.com html code that i request (r) in it.

If i run this now:

```
import requests

params = {"q": "pizza"}
r = requests.get("http://google.com/search", params=params)

f = open("./page.html", "w+")
f.write(r.text)
```

Does the `f.write(r.text)` rewrite everything that's on 'r' variable like it was a blank file or it will just edit the file with new stuff i add into 'r'? didn't knew how to ask. Thanks

EDIT: nevermind I am a noob! use `f = open("./page.html", "a")` if i want to append and 'w' if i want to overwrite

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: you could just try it out yourself :P

Comment: why not you are trying yourself by executing it, its appending or overwriting

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on how you open the file

> The mode indicates, how the file is going to be opened "r" for
>   reading, "w" for writing and "a" for a appending.

```
f = open("./page.html", "r")
f = open("./page.html", "w")
f = open("./page.html", "a")
```